# Attaching vue-gtm (google tag manager) to a Router instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gtm

In router.js (vue cli 3) i'm trying to attach it to a router instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import VueGtm from 'vue-gtm'

Vue.use(VueGtm, {
  id: 'GTM-xxxxxxx',
  enabled: true,
  debug: true,
  vueRouter: Router
})

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history'
})
```

But, obviously, this won't work. How can i attach vue-gtm to a Router in my case, where i export Router instance, not setting it to a variable:

```
const router = new Router({})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incorrectly passing the `Router` class for `vueRouter` in:

```
Vue.use(VueGtm, {
  //vueRouter: Router, // <-- DON'T DO THIS
})
```

The `vueRouter` value should be the router *instance*, so `router.js` should look similar to this:

```
const routes = [
  //...
]

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

Vue.use(VueGtm, {
  vueRouter: router, // <-- router instance
  //...
})

export default router
```

Comment: You've set it to a variable, is there no other way?

Comment: @AlexanderKim Not that I'm aware of. Why are you trying to avoid the variable?

Comment: Just curious, any pros using `export default new Router` vs a variable? Why vue router defaults to the first approach?

Comment: Not really any pros. The variable is needed in this case to initialize the `VueGtm` plugin. If `VueGtm` weren't in the same file, then you wouldn't need an intermediate variable here, and you could just export the newly instantiated `Router` in one line. You typically see the usage of `external default new Router` in `vue-router` docs because there's usually no need for plugins that require the `router` instance.